# How to nest Avatar component under a <p></p> container in MUI v5

Tags: material-ui

I have the following styled Avatar component, and I want to nest it under

, but I get the following error:

> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of

.

How do I override its container to be a ?

```js
export const StyledTutorialAvatar = styled(Avatar)(({ theme }) => ({
  margin: '0 5px',
  height: 30,
  width: 30,
  padding: 5,
  //margin: 2.5,
  fontWeight: 600,
  color: theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? 50 : 800],
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? 800 : 50],
  fontSize: 20,
  display: 'inline-flex',
}));
```

Comment: Your component in the described design works without errors: function ImageAvatars() { return <p><StyledTutorialAvatar src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" /></p>) }

Comment: @MaxAlex yes but it need a re-design.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is not in <p></p> but somewhere else.